# What is the meaning of the MTB suffix according to Microsoft malware naming scheme?

Tags: malware-detection, naming, microsoft-defender

Microsoft uses the CARO naming scheme for malware identification. The suffix part (name's right-most part after the ! separator) is supposed to be dedicated to "vendor-specific" comments [1]. Microsoft does list a few suffixes [2], but not **MTB**.

Does anyone knows what this suffix means ? It maybe maps to an "internal category" like others suffixes (eg. : *!bit* ), but it isn't listed, so I'm not sure.

This suffix seems to come with many types of malware (leftmost part of name), from *html* to *trojan*.

[1] https://web.archive.org/web/20141107015518/http://www.caro.org/naming/vendorcomment.html

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/intelligence/malware-naming

Comment: Have you tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/intelligence/microsoft-threat-actor-naming?view=o365-worldwide#resources

Comment: No, I'll take a look. Thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: It doesn't yields any result, etiher by query or by looking at the files available to download on the web page. Thanks !

Comment: Yeah, that happens. Still, worth a try. [Malware naming is a dark art](https://www.gdatasoftware.com/blog/2019/08/35146-taming-the-mess-of-av-detection-names).

Comment: Indeed ! Thanks for the article. Btw, Microsoft's new naming scheme is so great, can't wait to get hit by "Super Sayajin Chartreuse Apocalypse"...